# I get error when i run My function in Logic App Designer , following the azure sample project documentation

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am new to azure and i found one interesting project that i want to implement.
Here is the guthub link:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-serverless-workshop-team-assistant/blob/master/6-scheduler-bot/README.md

I did all the steps, but when i run my function in Logic App Designer i get the following error:

```
 Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each' at line '1' and column '2885': 'The template language expression 'split(triggerBody()['people'], ',')' cannot be evaluated because property 'people' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments you talked with Satya, it seems you click "**Run**" button on portal to run the logic app. And then it shows the error message.

First, we need to know how to use the trigger "[When a HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger)". The document mentioned that to click `Use sample payload to generate schema` button, so we click it and input the request body example into it. (like below screenshots)

[image]

[image]

Click "**Done**" button and we can see the trigger show like below screenshot, it generates the request body schema automatically:

[image]

Then complete the other actions which mentioned in the document. Here I just add a "**For each**" and use the same expression in it for test.

[image]

After that, **please do not click "Run" button on portal**. If you click "**Run**" button on portal to run the logic app, it won't pass the request body into the trigger. So the expression in "**For each**" can't get the property `people`. **We should open the postman, and copy the link of the trigger by clicking the button shown in below screenshot.**

[image]

In postman request the link copied from the trigger with "**post**" method, and also with the request body.

[image]

The logic app will be triggered success, then go to your logic app page and click "**Overview**". You can find the latest running history under the "**Run history**".

[image]

Click it, you can see the running of the logic app which triggered by your postman just now. It will not show the error message.

Comment: Hello Hury. I don't know why but when i click on Run then it is showing error, but actuallu when i try from postman it works. So i guess it is some bug from azure

Comment: @sdsd No, it is not a bug. That's how "When a HTTP request is received" tirgger works.

Comment: @sdsd Since it works, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Comment: No problem Thanks you too

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the Article you have referenced, the `people` will be the part of the body of the request.

**Sample Body :** (as per the article)

```
{
    "people": "azureserverlessdemo@gmail.com,ujmqvr5ouk8p9nmia2o4h6o33o@group.calendar.google.com"
}
```

You are likely to encounter this issue if this is blank or non existent !

In the above case, the output would be -

- azureserverlessdemo@gmail.com
  ujmqvr5ouk8p9nmia2o4h6o33o@group.calendar.google.com

Just to be sure you can initialize the above `split(triggerBody()['people'], ',')` in a array variable and confirm the values are returned in the Run History of a Logic App.

**or** if you hadn't passed the body for the Http request, you will have to pass the same.

Comment: Hello Satya, I am including that object in the requst body but when i paste it and i hit Done and after that i open again it is blank. I tried also: paste in the whole object and then click on Run but it is again saying that it can't find people object :S

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I can also take it up offline for a closer look and provide a quick and specialized assistance, please send an email with subject line “Attn:Sathya” to AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com referencing this thread along